# Print all Permutations of String by word

Tags: ios, objective-c, permutation

I am trying to print all the  permutations of the string "This Is Demo" word by word. For example valid permutations will be "This Demo Is", "Demo Is This", "Demo This is".
My program is not printing all the permutations. What's wrong with the code?

```
+(void)printPermutations
{
NSString *str = @"This Is Demo";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *permutationInput = [arr mutableCopy];
[[self class] printPermutationOfString:permutationInput startIndex:0 endIndex:arr.count-1];
}

+(void)printPermutationOfString:(NSMutableArray*)arr startIndex:(int)startingindex 
 endIndex:(int)endIndex
{
if (startingindex == endIndex) {
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    return;
}
for (int i = startingindex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:startingindex withObjectAtIndex:i];
    [[self class] printPermutationOfString:arr  startIndex:i+1 endIndex:endIndex];
    [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:startingindex withObjectAtIndex:endIndex];
}

}
```

Comment: What is your program currently printing out? Did you make a chart of the expected permutations? [0,1,2],[0,2,1] etc. and compare it to the indices that you are using? That'll be the best way to visualize how to iterate through...

Comment: It should print 6 outputs which are "This Is Demo","This Demo Is", "Is This Demo", "Is Demo This","Demo This Is", "Demo IS This".

Comment: I am only getting "This Demo Is","Demo Is This"

Comment: check if my answer works

Comment: You only get 2 because you set your endIndex to 2 which causes your for-loop to only execute twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. working for me. Hope this helps

```
+ (void)printPermutations
{
    NSString *str = @"This Is Demo";
    NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSMutableArray *permutationInput = [arr mutableCopy];
    [[self class] printPermutationOfString:permutationInput startIndex:0];
}

+(void)printPermutationOfString:(NSMutableArray*)arr startIndex:(int)startingindex
{
    if (startingindex == arr.count) {
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = startingindex; i < arr.count; i++) {
        [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:startingindex withObjectAtIndex:i];
        [[self class] printPermutationOfString:arr startIndex:startingindex+1];
        if (i < (arr.count - 1))
            [[self class] reverse:arr start:startingindex+1 end:(startingindex+1)+(arr.count-startingindex-2)]; // edited here
    }
}
+ (void)reverse:(NSMutableArray *)arr start:(int)i end:(int)j {
    if ([arr count] == 0)
        return;
    while (i < j) {
        [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i
              withObjectAtIndex:j];
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed a small issue. Please do work with edited answer @agupta

Comment: Pratyusha ,yes this works fine but why are you doing a reverse of the array.

Comment: I followed the algorithm given in this site that is it http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14581715 if it helped you why dont you accept the answer